# How can I change the color of the error output in the VS code terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I working with vscode for python programming.how can i  change color text error output in terminal?
.can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can answer your question better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing that in Windows, Linux or Mac? Do you mean to change the color in all the outputs and only in VSC terminal, or only in one program?. You should explain more what you want.

If you want to change the color of one output in python, then do:

```
print("\033[1;44mMessage\033[0m")
```

Where: `\033` is the label to identify the color `[1;44m` 1 is the background color, 44m is the font color, you replace the numbers for the color's code in the image below. With `\033[0m` you change the color back to the default.

Here are the available colors:

https://robologs.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/coloricos.png

(I can't comment yet).

Comment: hi. how are you? thanks for answer this question. i working with windows and want change the error color in the outputs and only in vsc terminal. for example i want error color in terminal is red for ever .how to doing this work Without print syntax? can i change terminal setting in setting.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your settings:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

                                   // whatever hex color you want
                                   // doesn't appear that opacity values work here 
    "terminal.ansiBrightRed": "#ff0"  // typically used for the error foreground
  }
}
```